# Cannot post to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

Here is my request definition:

```
params = typeof params !== "undefined" ? params : {};
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
        url: 'apiUrl' + 'MVCcontrollerName' + '/'
    });
```

And C#:

```
public class MVCcontrollerName : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(int? Id = null)
    {

.......
```

I am not getting my Id parameter in the controller class. It's null. The parameter is defined as {Id:1}.
I also tested POST with Chrome REST client with the same results.

Any idea, what's wrong?

Comment: did you send id param thru URL using $http(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here.

1. First the name of your controller should follow the convention of `SomenameController`, so you might want to call it `MVCcontrollerNameController`
2. The URL you specify is missing a slash to delimit between the path and the controller name:

   ```
   url: 'apiUrl' + '/' + 'MVCcontrollerName' + '/'
   ```

Or simply:

```
    url: 'apiUrl/MVCcontrollerName/'
```

Or more correctly, let MVC do the routing for you (as suggested by @JamieRees):

```
    url: '@Url.Action("Index","MVCcontrollerName")'
```

3. The main issue however, is that you are `POST`ing the data where you really should be calling it as a `GET` with the parameter as part of the URL. However, if you really need to have it in a `POST`, then you need to decorate the parameter with the `FromBody` attribute:

```
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody]int? Id = null)
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `'@Url.Action("Index","MVCcontrollerName")'`

Comment: @JamieRees I'd agree with that for sure.

Comment: Not sure how I would use '@Url.Action("Index","MVCcontrollerName")'

Comment: I also change my code to the following: method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: 'assetId=1',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            },
            url: apiUrl + MVCcontroller + '/' Still no parameter is received.

Comment: @Mark I'll add in the change, but if you use my code above, leave it as a `POST`. If you want a `GET` then you need to pass the id value in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but anyway you should have attribute [HttpPost] on action that will be called with post

Comment: This won't make any difference I'm afraid.